# jruby,how to pass 2d ruby array to java method

Tags: jruby

using Jruby and want to pass 2d ruby array to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

```
#create a empty table view on UI and will fill out it later
columns = ['1','2']
data = [[]]
columns.length.times{ data.first << ""}
# below raise exception
mode = javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.new(data,columns)
```

seems exception caused by the method signature matching, how to solve it?

```
NameError: no constructorfor arguments (org.jruby.java.proxies.ArrayJavaProxy
,or g.jruby.RubyArray) on Java::JavaxSwingTable::DefaultTableModel
available overloads:
(java.util.Vector,java.util.Vector)
(java.lang.Object[],int)
(java.util.Vector,int)
(int,int)
(java.lang.Object[][],java.lang.Object[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Populate a Java Vector from Ruby values...

```
 matrix = java.util.Vector.new
 datos.each do |valor|   
      matrix.add_element(valor)
 end #datos.each do |valor|
```

I'm using a Swing on an app...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rmldonkey/

Regads